# Delete address from phpmyadmin

Tags: magento2, customer-address

I have a customer that have a lot of addresses (because I saved his address after each order)

So now I can't save changes I've made from backend because there's to many addresses and it's crashing my website.

How can I remove addresses from phpmyadmin? Knowing that some orders are related to addresses

Comment: What's crashing the site? what error does it come up with?

Comment: When I want to change one info from my user dans I click on "save", the site shows "address" part (from the Backend) and just not responding after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the customer_address_entity delete the address based on the parent_id which is customer id.

use the query.

Comment: I though about that, but isn't this going to create error with existing order ?